# how to exit infinte while loop in the basic hangman question

Tags: python, random, while-loop, infinite-loop, break

Hi so I am a total noob in programming, to strengthen my practice I tried to do a hangman project(not the typical hangman which uses GUI).
**PREREQUISITE**
Dictionaries,tuples, loops(including nesting of loops),if-else statement and the random function in python
**PROBLEM FACED**
The while loop isn't working. It runs perfect until the end, then it wont exit the while loop and and (print yikes!!you have won). It stays in the while loop(which I have set an infinite loop) and say's "enter a character" and refuses to exit the loop. Please debug my code or suggest changes in it so that I can exit the while loop after the correct word has been guessed. For ease I am only uploading the crux of the code (where I am facing the problem, feel free to run the code in your console)

```py
    import random
    store=""
    d=input("ENTER START: ")
    p=d.lower()
    sb={"fruits":("strawberry","banana","apple","orange","guava","grapes"),"colours":("red","blue","orange","brown","yellow"),"cars":("maruti","nano","ferrrari","audi","jaguar")}
    keys=list(sb)
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        f=random.randint(0,len(keys)-1)
        j=keys[f]
        q=sb[j]
        r=random.randint(0,len(q)-1)
        x=q[r]
    print(x)
    if p!="start":
        cc=input("Enter the CORRECT command in pls: ")
        store=cc.lower()
    if p=="start" or cc=="start":
        print("HINT 1:ok so I have chosen",j+"!!!\n and you have",len(x)+2,"chances to guess")
        for i in range(len(x)+2):
                term=x
                query = []
                flag = 0 
                chance=0
                while True:
                    query.append(input("Enter the letter: ").lower())
                    output = " ".join([x if x in query else "_" for x in term.lower()])
                    print(output)
                    flag += 1 if query[-1] in term.lower() else 0
                    chance+=1
                    query = list(set(query))
                    if flag == len(set(term)) or chance==len(term)+2:
                        print("YIKES!!you won!!!")
                        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The ˙break`leaves the`while True:`loop, but you'll find yourself in the`for i in range(len(x)+2):`loop again. Your`output`is nicely written, but`flag += 1 if query[-1] in term.lower() else 0` is buggy: if I type in the same matching letter, it will say I won even I didn't. Example:

```
ENTER START: start
orange
HINT 1:ok so I have chosen colours!!!
 and you have 8 chances to guess
Enter the letter: o 
o _ _ _ _ _
Enter the letter: o 
o _ _ _ _ _       
Enter the letter: o
o _ _ _ _ _       
Enter the letter: o
o _ _ _ _ _       
Enter the letter: o
o _ _ _ _ _       
Enter the letter: o
o _ _ _ _ _      
YIKES!!you won!!!
```

After this, your interpreter starts from the last `for` loop with i=1.

To make checking easier, you can also specify the seed for random, so you'll get the same choice. For this, insert `random.seed(0)` after the 1st line, and change 0 to anything you (or the user) want.

To better understand how your program works, [a debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) can give a good insight.